# Error: Invalid value for '[FILES]...': Path '{path/to/data}' does not exist

Tags: python, datasette

I've just gotten started with Datasette and found that while I have hundreds of .sqlite databases, only one was able to load (it was empty). Every other one has had this sort of error:

`Error: Invalid value for '[FILES]...': Path '/Users/mercury/Pictures/Photos' does not exist.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a simple error. The file path is required to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arose in my code as well. When I updated my OpenAI key, it worked. However, when I faced the issue again, it turned out that my folder was placed inside another folder, and the problem was due to the wrong path in my VSCode.